# Expectation of product of Gaussian random vectors

Tags: random-matrices

Say we have two multivariate Gaussian random vectors $p(x_1) = N(0,\Sigma_1), p(x_2) = N(0,\Sigma_2)$, is there a well known result for the expectation of their product $E[x_1x_2^T]$ (matrix result) without assuming independence?

Thanks.

Comment: What is known about these rv's? Do they have a joint denisty function? Are they jointly normal? Also, in view of the notation  and the tag, are these rv's multivariate normal?

Comment: Indeed, I neglected to mention they are both jointly normal and multivariate normal.

Comment: Isn't this just more or less the matrix of covariances between the random variables in $x_1$ and the random variables in $x_2$?

Answer (score 3):

Without assuming anything about the random vectors you can only get upper and lower bounds. For a complete description of the matrix
$$
\mathbb{E}[x_1x_2^{T}]
$$
you need to know the correlation between the $i$-th entry of the vector $x_1$ and the $j$-th entry of the vector $x_2$ for all possibles indexes $i$ and $j$. I hope it helps!